# Sort f:selectItems list based on labels

Tags: java, jsf

I have a selectItem list of values and labels. Data is fetched from database and the selectItem list has following values:

```
<1,100-500>
<2,1000-1500>
<3,500-1000>
```

Here 1, 2, 3 are the values for selectItem list and '100-500', '1000-1500' and '500-1000' are labels respectively. As you can see, the list is already sorted based on labels. But my requirement is that the list should be displayed in the dropdown as follows:

```
100-500
500-1000
1000-1500
```

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 7):

If you can't modify the code which fetches the SelectItem instances from the DB so that the come sorted as you'd like, then you have to sort them yourself :

```
// this gets you a list which is not sorted as you would like
List<SelectItem> list = getMasterValues("Staff Range");

// you need to sort the list before displaying it. 
// To sort the list, you need a Comparator which will tell the sorting
// algorithm how to order the items
Comparator<SelectItem> comparator = new Comparator<SelectItem>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(SelectItem s1, SelectItem s2) {
        // the items must be compared based on their value (assuming String or Integer value here)
        return s1.getValue().compareTo(s2.getValue());
    }
};

// now that you have the comparator, sort the list using it :
Collections.sort(list, comparator);

// and now iterate over the list to display it :
for (SelectItem item : list) {
    System.out.println("value = " + item.getValue() + "; label = " + item.getLabel());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But even if we use the above mentioned logic, we will get the list in same order. As value "1000-1500" comes before "500-1000" in dictionary, this list will remain as it is.

Comment: @shaleen : DwB explains it. You haven't shown us your SelectItem class. Since you tell us it has the values <1, 100-500>, etc., I assumed a SelectItem has a value (1, 2 or 3) and a label ("100-500", "500-1000" or "1000-1500"). My algorithm sorts them by value, thus <1, 100-500> will come before <2, 500-1000> which will come before <3, 1000-1500>.

Comment: This `Collection.sort(list, comparator);` should be `Collections.sort(list, comparator);`. Needed this today and noted this typo. +1 Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example program I quickly wrote that uses a [custom comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class StrangeSort
{
    static List<JLabel> listOfLabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        listOfLabels.add(new JLabel("100-500"));
        listOfLabels.add(new JLabel("1000-1500"));
        listOfLabels.add(new JLabel("500-1000"));

        System.out.println("Before:");
        for(JLabel label: listOfLabels)
        {
            System.out.println(label.getText());
        }

        Collections.sort(listOfLabels, new LabelComparator());

        System.out.println("After:");
        for(JLabel label: listOfLabels)
        {
            System.out.println(label.getText());
        }

    }

    static class LabelComparator implements Comparator
    {
        public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2)
        {
            // Get labels
            JLabel label1 = (JLabel) obj1;
            JLabel label2 = (JLabel) obj2;

            // Get text
            String[] label1Text = label1.getText().split("-");
            String[] label2Text = label2.getText().split("-");

            // Convert to integers
            int label1Value = Integer.parseInt(label1Text[0]);
            int label2Value = Integer.parseInt(label2Text[0]);

            // Compare values
            if (label1Value > label2Value)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (label1Value < label2Value)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Before:
100-500
1000-1500
500-1000
After:
100-500
500-1000
1000-1500
```

Answer (score 4):

I use [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) and do it with 1 line of code....

```
// sort by label
Collections.sort(selectItems, new BeanComparator<>("label"));
```

OR...

```
// sort by value
Collections.sort(selectItems, new BeanComparator<>("value"));
```

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a comparator.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: I tried using comparator but still I am getting list in same order only. Please note my values in list are getting populated as: 100-500,1000-1500,500-1000. Assume the list has three elements only. But my requirement is to display list in  100-500,500-1000, 1000-1500 order.

Comment: See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html rather, since Comparator has been generified since Java 5.

Comment: /*Retretreiving values from database using common application level API */ List staffRangeList = getMasterValues("Staff Range"); SelectItem selectItem =null; String label=null; Iterator staffIter =staffRangeList.iterator(); while(staffIter.hasNext()){ selectItem =(SelectItem ) staffIter.next(); label= selectItem.getLabel(); Syste.out.println(label+','); } Output: 100-500, 1000-1500, 500-1000, Now my requirement is to rearrange the list in such a way that values should get displayed in dropdwon as mentioned in last comment,ie, 100-500,500-1000, 1000-1500

Answer (score 0):

### Sort by Label

Take a look at the code posted by "JB Nizet".  It sorts by value.  If you change
`return s1.getValue().compareTo(s2.getValue());`
to the following:
`return s1.getLabel().compareTo(s2.getLabel());`
It will sort by label.

### Sort Label Numerically

The above will sort by string value.  Which means that 1 is less than 5 (i.e. 1000 < 500).  The next step is to convert the label to a number and compare it.  For this use a variation of the following:

```
int value1 = Integer.parseInt(s1.getLabel());
int value2 = Integer.parseInt(s2.getLabel());
return value1 - value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you very much for your help. I am getting the desired result. Please find below the code for your reference.

```
  /**
   * This is a custom comparator used for numeric sorting based on labels 
  */
  static class LabelComparator implements Comparator {
        public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
              // Get labels
              SelectItem label1 = (SelectItem) obj1;
              SelectItem label2 = (SelectItem) obj2;
              // Get text
              String[] label1Text = label1.getLabel().split("-");
              String[] label2Text = label2.getLabel().split("-");
              // Convert to integers
              int label1Value = Integer.parseInt(label1Text[0]);
              int label2Value = Integer.parseInt(label2Text[0]);
              // Compare values
              if (label1Value > label2Value) {
                    return 1;
              } else if (label1Value < label2Value) {
                    return -1;
              } else {
                    return 0;
              }
        }
  }

  /**
   * Method to populate values  
  */
  public void init() {
        List rangeList = (List) CodeManagerUtil
                    .getValue("Staff Range");
        Collections.sort(rangeList, new LabelComparator());
        if (rangeList != null) {
              setRangeList(rangeList );
        }
  }
```