# How to sort the dropdown list before displaying in dropdown box

Tags: java

[image: This is drop down list]

The below image will show the code for that drop down box. It will return a list of object, after that I'm creating new SelectItem object. Is there any way to sort the list of object before I'm creating new SelectItem object.

[image: Java Code for Drop Down box]

Sorry, I'm not able to send the entire code, due to confidential

Answer (score 0):

Use [Collections.sort(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html). If your want to sort particular field of your object, then you need to implements your own `Comparator`. See sample

```
Collections.sort(yourList,new Comparator<Object>() {
    public int compare(Object obj1,Object obj2) {
        return ((YourObject) obj1).getName().compareTo(((YourObject) obj2).getName);
    }
});
```

Or you can simply uses as default sorting

```
Collections.sort(list, Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: but the thing is Comparable is not applicable for SelectItem. It is throwing exception. **java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.model.SelectItem incompatible with java.lang.Comparable**

Comment: you should use first way. I think I found good link in SO that is useful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007959/jsf-sort-selectitem-list-based-on-labels

Comment: It's working fine, by creating custom Comparator. Thank you. @Sai Ye Yan Naing Aye